# How to execute code when clicking logout link with jQuery Zebra Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i put this kind of code in the logout navigation link code? im new to jquery so im having trouble...i need your help guys.

this is the code where i need to put it:

```
<a href="#">Logout</a>
```

heres the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="Zebra_Dialog-master/public/javascript/zebra_dialog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Zebra_Dialog-master/public/css/default/zebra_dialog.css" type="text/css">

<script>
$.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Do you want to Logout?</strong>', {
    'type':     'question',
    'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)',
    'buttons':  [
                    {caption: 'Yes', callback: function() { alert('"Yes" was clicked')}},
                    {caption: 'No', callback: function() { alert('"No" was clicked')}},
                    {caption: 'Cancel', callback: function() { alert('"Cancel" was clicked')}}
                ]
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**.click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler

*HTML*

```
<a id="logout" href="#">Logout</a>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // show a dialog box when clicking on a link
    $("#logout").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Do you want to Logout?</strong>', {
            'type':     'question',
            'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)',
            'buttons':  [
                            {caption: 'Yes', callback: function() { alert('"Yes" was clicked')}},
                            {caption: 'No', callback: function() { alert('"No" was clicked')}},
                            {caption: 'Cancel', callback: function() { alert('"Cancel" was clicked')}}
                        ]
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: how to put a code that if i click the yes button it will direct to logout.php page?

Comment: @eloginko, place your code after `alert('"Yes" was clicked')` like `window.location.href = "your url";`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="logout_button">Logout</a>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$('#logout_button').click(function(){
    //whatever you want to happen when you click the button goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-dialog/ :

```
>$(document).ready(function() {

// show a dialog box when clicking on a link
$(anchor).bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.Zebra_Dialog('The link was clicked!');
});
```

});

Give your  tag an id like,

```
<a href='#' id='logout'>logout</a>
```

Replace 'anchor' with  '#logout' in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach a click handler to your logout link.

If you create an id (or a class if you have multiple logout options scattered throughout the page) on the  this is trivial.

```
<a id="logout" href="#">Logout</a>
```

And then within your initialization code:

```
$("#logout").click(
  $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Do you want to Logout?</strong>', {
    'type':     'question',
    'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)',
    'buttons':  [
                {caption: 'Yes', callback: function() { alert('"Yes" was clicked')}},
                {caption: 'No', callback: function() { alert('"No" was clicked')}},
                {caption: 'Cancel', callback: function() { alert('"Cancel" was clicked')}}
            ]
  });
);
```